# Can't get caffe to build

Tags: makefile, caffe, hdf5

I'm trying to get a custom version of caffe ([the one here](https://github.com/mhauskn/dqn-hfo/issues/26)) working for some my experiments. When I make those changes in the required files and perform a `make all` in the caffe root directory, I get the following :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-244:~/caffe$ make all -j4 
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.a(H5LT.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:555: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

Any idea why this must be happening?
I've looked at [similar issues](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2171), but not sure how I can apply that in this case.

I have CUDA Version 8.0.61 and cuDNN 6.21 (on which [the master branch](https://github.com/mhauskn/dqn-hfo) of the same repository works perfectly).

Edit:
For the various (standard caffe installation) errors that came up in the installation, I had to make the following changes:

```
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0 libhdf5.so
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2 libhdf5_hl.so
```

Inside the Makefile.config:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ and
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/
```

and

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH`
```

Comment: it seems like, for some reason, you are trying to link against a **static** version of `libhdf5` instead of linking against a **dynamic** version.. have you installed correctly all prerequisites?

Comment: I've installed `libhdf5-serial-dev` and `libhdf5-dev` via `apt-get` on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. I also had to make some changes as mentioned in the edit above.

Comment: so you managed to solve your problem? if so, consider posting the solution as an answer instead of editing the original question

Comment: No, no. I just updated the question to reflect some of the other errors I had to solve on the way to this particular one. I added that in case someone finds out that one of those steps is leading (directly or indirectly) to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an earlier build of caffe was interfering with this custom build. Re-installing everything (caffe, cuDNN) from scratch worked...